# Can you view the attacks of a previous clan war?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm trying to decide who should be in the next clan war. Can you find out (or what the replays) of the attacks of the previous clan war, once it is already over? If no, then is the only thing to do is take note of who hasn't attacked just a few minutes before the previous war ends? Let me know if my question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *usually* see the attacks from a previous war. To do that, do to your clan window, and tap on 'War Log':

[image]

From there, you will be able to see the recent replays:

[image]

From the above for example, I can see the replays from the war against 'Jari Emas', but not from the previous ones, but that's because war details become unavailable after some time, or after an update.

So, if you must keep track of who participates, it's better if you periodically check replays before they get erased by time or updates (which are more difficult to cope with for that particular task).

Comment: You will only be able to see the two most recent wars' details.

Comment: @PythonMaster This is not entirely accurate. In the picture above, the top war was actually the last war, and the one before it is not viewable. There is however about 3 days between the two wars, hence why I mentioned "become unavailable after some time". Doing wars back to back, yes, two wars will be visible, but that means there was no time between the two.

Comment: @PythonMaster I'm also pretty sure that after a week of non-war, the last war's details won't be viewable (assuming no updates occurred in that period).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can see them.

Go to "my clan", click on war log, then details on the war which you'd like to see the details about. From there, you can view the map just like it were the current war.